# Image made of shapes - terminology + software?

Tags: images, software-recommendation, terminology

rI've often seen images that look like the following example
[image]

Q1) is there a term for such an image?

Q2) What common software is used to convert a real photo (e.g. human face) to be composed of such shapes? (or even an online service)

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Comment: 300 pages of low poly animals right here https://www.shutterstock.com/search/low+poly+animal

Comment: More examples would help this be a better question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's typically called [**Low Poly Art**](https://www.google.com/search?q=low%20poly%20art&oq=low%20poly%20art&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.2907j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

There are a number of automated online tools, as well as countless tutorials to create such a thing. What you use all depends on the tools you have available and the desired overall outcome.

Simply click the link in this answer above and start searching for something that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this tutorial](https://speckyboy.com/creating-origami-style-vector-swan-illustrator/) for creating an "origami style" image, but you have to draw it yourself in Adobe Illustrator.